# Getting error while executing the query for sql server table column name with japanese characters

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, utf-8, sqlsrv

I'm building a web application with PHP to display the data from Microsoft SQL server. I have a table with column names in the Japanese language. I want to retrieve the column data but, I'm getting this error.

> Undefined index: 基準日時

Note: I can fetch the data for column names with english.

Please help me in resolving the issue.

**here is the source code:**

```
    $serverName = "TestDB,1433"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Database123", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"Pass.124");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }
    else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $sql="SELECT * from [Database123].[dbo].[LOG] ";
    $stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
    if ($stmt===false){
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <table class='table'>

    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class='w'>Logon User</th>
    <th>Server Received Log Time</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";

    while ($row =sqlsrv_fetch_Array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH))
    {
    echo"<tbody>";
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>".$row['基準日時']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row['日時']->format('Y-m-d h-m-s')."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
    echo"</tbody>";
    }
    echo"</table>";

    sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having Japanese column names is not a great way to deal with db columns. You can try grabbing them using the numerical index number of the column or change your select statement to rename the name of column while selecting it.

grabbing it with numerical index:

```
echo"<td>".$row[x]."</td>";
where x is the column number depending on your query
```

renaming column in query:

```
echo"<td>".$row['columnName']."</td>";
SELECT 基準日時 as columnName, 日時 as columnName2, * (or other columns that you want) from [Database123].[dbo].[LOG]
```

these are temporary fixes.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the second one by changing the column name but, getting error as " Incorrect syntax near '�' ".


 `echo"<td>".$row[ColumnName1]."</td>";
echo"<td>".$row[ColumnName2]."</td>";

SELECT 基準日時 as columnName1, 日時 as columnName2,  from [Database123].[dbo].[LOG]`

Comment: $row[ColumnName1] you forgot to put the colons `'` , use $row['ColumnName1'], or did you get the error while running the query? if yes just go with numerical index

Comment: Thanks @ mrahmat, 
By grabbing it with numerical index able to fetch.....

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT which column you want. write name here of the column FROM tablename here";
```

instead of

```
$sql="SELECT * from [Database123].[dbo].[LOG] ";
```

Comment: Yes, tried but, getting error
$sql="SELECT [基準日時], [日時] from [Database123].[dbo].[LOG] ";